# Applying to NSW State sponsorship with 55 points

Tags: australia

I am applying to New South Wales (NSW) state sponsorship (subclass 190) [Australia] with 55 points. My point breakdown is as follows

```
Age: 30 pts
Education: 15pts
IELTS: (W:7, S:7, R:8.5, L:9): 10

Total: 55 points + SS points (5) = 60
```

Do you think that I would have to wait longer with this point total?

Comment: The question title says 55 points, but the breakdown you've provided adds up to 60 points.  Fairly relevant, as 60 points is the current cutoff point for applications.  If you have 60 points (the 5 from state-sponsorship count), you should apply.  No sense waiting beforehand; there will be _plenty_ of waiting after you submit your application.

Comment: quite confusing, wonder if the 5 point from state sponsorship is automatically granted once you submitted your EOI with 55 point only.

Answer (score 1):

Processing works in a way that they send invitations to candidates with most points lets say 75, then if quota isn't met to those with 70 then 65 and then to 60. If some of 60s didn't fit into this month they will be first on the list for next month (after all the 75, 70s ans 65s).

They also had raised amount of points to apply in the past...

However I suggest you don't even try... Australian system is rigged in such a way that they can report that you have some amount points (say 60), but then after you have paid application fee 2k USD, they can change them (to 55) and you cannot complain about it [because they get to decide everything](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/under-which-clause-can-i-get-back-australian-visa-application-fee-if-skillselect/10974#10974)... You can't even appeal it or complain to anyone... they can just take your money and there is nothing you can do about it...