# Under which clause can I get back Australian Visa application fee if SkillSelect or ASC calculated my points wrong?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, australia, refusal

I have applied for Australian visa 189 first assessing agency is ACS (Australian Computer Society) which assessed me as suitable for migration

[image]

Then I have submitted all the paperwork (IELTS, ACS result) to SkillSelect and again I got positive response

[image]

I then paid application fee (family of 4 = 7920 AUD or ~6000 USD), did the health checks and police certificates, submitted all the same paperwork to [Australian immigration](https://online.immi.gov.au) and got following response

[image]

I have checked online and there seems to be a form ([1424](https://www.border.gov.au/FormsAndDocuments/Documents/1424.pdf)) for application fee refund. **Under which circumstances in part F could I claim successful refund?**

Comment: Were you allocated a case officer? Talk to them, and ask about the discrepancy of calculated points. They may just be asking you to prove the other 15 points.

Comment: @Boj Hi Boj, as I understand this is coming from my case officer, I have attached all the job experience related documents already, I have also added SkillSelect and ASC points too they gave me. One does not calculate points for himself he takes documents to ASC and SkillSelect and they tell you how much points you have based on documents provided.

Comment: Well, they didn't give you any work experience points. That's what you should ask about. Did ACS approve any other work besides the 7 months?

Comment: Departmental error? Or application was deemed invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not, system is set up in such a way that even if you present evidence that it wasn't your fault... same person that rejects your application decides if you should be refunded and even if you can appeal or not...

[image]

Australian immigration is a huge scam that cannot be sued or complained against and they know it and just run wild...

If you are reading this it probably is to late, but if it is not.. **Do not migrate to Australia**